# discord.js | imported array returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, import, discord.js

I've imported an array from another file but I can't access any of its elements.
The array is imported but when I try and access an element using [0] it returns undefined

standList.js | How I exported the array:

```
exports.stands = ["Star Platinum","Crazy Diamond","Golden Experience"]
```

How I'm trying to access it:

```
const stands = require('../data/standList.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {

        if(interaction.isButton()){
            
            if (interaction.customId = 'standarrow'){
                var stand = stands[0];
                console.log(stands);
                console.log(stands[0]);
                console.log(stand);
                await interaction.reply("You have awakened the power of *" + (stand) + "*!");}  
        }
        
        console.log(`${interaction.user.tag} in #${interaction.channel.name} triggered an interaction.`);
    },
};
```

output:

```
KomiKage in #testzone triggered an interaction.
Killjoy :  | testzone | Thu Oct 27 2022 13:41:51 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
{ stands: [ 'Star Platinum', 'Crazy Diamond', 'Golden Experience' ] }
undefined
undefined
KomiKage in #testzone triggered an interaction.
```

Comment: try `export const stands = ["Star Platinum","Crazy Diamond","Golden Experience"]`

Comment: changing it to 'export const stands' just hits me with 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export''

Comment: Maybe there is a circular reference between those files?

Comment: It looks like the OP is using CommonJS for imports and exports. Using ESM syntax will throw that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exporting and requiring this way:

```js
const stands = ["Star Platinum","Crazy Diamond","Golden Experience"];

module.exports = {
   stands
}
```

```js
const { stands } = require('../data/standList.js');
```

Comment: Yep this fixed it, thank you! What's the difference between the two exporting methods?

Comment: The method @RenaudC5 suggested is in [EcmaScript Module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules) syntax, which is the modern alternative to NodeJS' `module.exports/require` functions. ESM has benefits such as making modules tree-shakable and cleaner syntax